# How to insert these values correctly in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Below is part of the code where it uploads a file (fileImage) into a folder (ImageFiles). But what I want to also do is INSERT the file location (The location the file is uploaded into) into the database using INSERT VALUES code. I want the file location to be inserted into the "ImageFile" field and for the "ImageId" I want it to display the string "IMG" and then include a number after the string. For Example:

In my database table if it reads like this:

```
ImageId     ImageFile

IMG1        ImageFiles/penguins.png
IMG2        ImageFiles/desert.png
IMG3        ImageFiles/jellyfish.jpg
```

Then if I upload the file from my computer 'tulips.png' into the ImageFiles folder, then in the database it should insert the values like this below:

```
ImageId    ImageFile

IMG4       ImageFiles/tulips.png
```

But how can this be coded? Below is my code at the moment which uploads the file successfully and contains only partial coding of the INSERT VALUES:

```
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

      $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageId, ImageFile) 
    VALUES ("");

mysql_query($imagesql);
```

Comment: Is `ImageId` rows actually named with IMG[some number]?

Comment: Yes it is named with IMG[some number]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an auto incremented id for identifying images instead of using strings for this.

This would ease up the process for you as you would only have to insert a single fields and the autoi ncremented fields updates automatically.

```
$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";
```

ImageId should then be of type INT as PRIMARY KEY with AUTO INCREMENT instead. That's also a good way to design your tables.

Answer (score 4):

If you use PHPs PDO object it would simplify your code and make it more safe at the same time (by using prepared statements).

Here's an example of how you would do that:

Firstly, store your ID as an AUTO_INCREMENT-ed INT rather than "IMG#" as this would make things easier (you wouldn't need to INSERT the ID value then)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_img_store;
CREATE TABLE tbl_img_store(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    filename VARCHAR(25) --increase this if you think you need to
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Also, create a table to store configuration settings to make your database more efficient:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_img_config;
CREATE TABLE tbl_img_config(
    img_path VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO tbl_img_config (img_path) VALUES ("http://img.mysite.com/?i=");
```

Now back to PHP, you can quickly insert a load of images like this:

```
# Create a DB connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=X.X.X.X;dbname=mydb", $user, $pass);

# Compile an array of image paths
$img1path = "img1.png";
$img2path = "img2.png";
$img3path = "img3.png";
$images = array($img1path, $img2path, $img3path);

# Create a query to insert the paths to the db
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_img_store (filename) VALUES (?),(?),(?);";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($images);

# Check rows affected
$rows = $query->rowCount();
echo "$rows images were saved.";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the values to the query like this

```
$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageId, ImageFile) 
VALUES ('$imageName','$imageFile');";
```

But first make sure you escape the values correctly to avoid any problems. Also note that it's not recommended to use the mysql_ functions any more. Instead use mysqli_ equivalents or better still PDO (with PDO it will automatically handle the DB escaping for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySql Auto increment  .. you don't need to worry about `IMG` `IMG2` ... etc

See : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

**Example:**

Assumption :  `ImageId` is an auto increment field

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
$tmpName = $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["tmp_name"];
$fileName = $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["tmp_name"];

move_uploaded_file ( $tmpName, $fileName );
$sql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageId, ImageFile)   VALUES (NULL,'%s');";
mysql_query ( sprintf ( $sql, mysql_real_escape_string ( $fileName ) ) );
```

When you want to get your images

```
$sql = "SELECT ImageId, ImageFile FROM Image";
$result = mysql_query ( $sql );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
    echo "IMG", $row ["ImageId"], " = ", 'ImageFiles/'  , $row ["ImageFile"], PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Reason Why you should use this**

A. `IMG` and  `ImageFiles/` are constant saving them several times is not efficient

B. `integer` based id would also faster than `varchar` and performs better on `JOIN

C. To get `IMGX` where `X` is an increment value would involve multiple SQL calls .. and not efficient

Comment: Hi, ImageId isn't auto incremented, it is a varchar. It should always display the String 'IMG' but then at the end of the string it would displays the next number E.g. If the last ImageId is 'IMG3', then the next ImageId should be 'IMG4', then next one is 'IMG5' and etc

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do. For an answer to your question, look near the end of the second file, for the mysql_query for SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(). Note that I don't INSERT an id but let the database auto_increment.

The image is uploaded through upload.php, part of which looks like this:

```
<form>
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($error["image"])) echo '<span class="error">'.$error["image"].'</span>'; else echo 'Select an image<span class="required"> *</span>';

if ($imgVars["is_image"] == "J") {
    echo '
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="'.$imgVars["image_url"].'">
<input type="hidden" name="image_type" value="'.$imgVars["image_type"].'">
<input type="hidden" name="is_image" value="J">
<img src="'.$imgVars["image_url"].'" width="224" height="168" alt="Image">
<p>Change image?</p>';

?>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" title="Upload your image">
</form>
```

Then the uploaded file is processed through process.php, part of which looks like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!session_is_registered("error"))
    session_register("error");

$error = array();

if (!session_is_registered("imgVars"))
    session_register("imgVars");

foreach($_POST as $varname => $value)
    $imgVars[$varname] = trim(EscapeShellCmd(stripslashes($value)));

$imgVars = array();

if ($imgVars["is_image"] != 'J') {
    $imgVars["is_image"] = 'N';
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 0) {
        $size = GetImageSize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
        $width = $size[0];
        $height = $size[1];
        if(($width != 224) || ($height != 168)) {
            $error["image"] = 'Image dimensions must be exactly 224 x 168 pixel!';
            $imgVars["is_image"] = "N";
        }
        preg_match("/(\.\w+)$/",
            $_FILES["image"]["name"],$match);
        $imagetype = $match[1];
        if (!in_array(strtolower($imagetype), array(".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".png"))) {
            $error["image"] = 'You may upload only images of type JPEG, GIF and PNG!';
            $imgVars["is_image"] = "N";
        }
        if ($imgVars["is_image"] == "J") {
            $filename = time().$imagetype;
            copy($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "img/".$filename);
            $imgVars["image_url"] = "img/".$filename;
            $imgVars["image_type"] = $imagetype;
        }
    } else {
        $error["image"] = 'Please upload an image!';
    }
}

if (count($error))
{
    header('Location: upload.php');
    exit();
}

// connect to database

$query = "INSERT INTO images SET image_url = '" . $imgVars["image_url"] . "';


if (!($result = @ mysql_query ($query, $connection)))
    die("Your mysql error routine here.");

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", $connection);
$lid = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$image_id = $lid[0];

if ($imgVars["is_image"] == 'J') {
    rename ($imgVars["image_url"], "img/".$image_id.$imgVars["image_type"]);
    $query = "UPDATE images SET image_url = 'img/".$image_id.$imgVars["image_type"]."' WHERE image_id = '".$image_id."'";
    if (!(@ mysql_query ($query, $connection)))
        die("Your mysql error routine here.");
}

session_unregister("formVars");
session_unregister("fehler");

header('Location: danke.php');
exit();

?>
```

There might be typos or omissions in this code, because I translated and trimmed it from my original file without testing.

Answer (score -1):

**First of all :** ALWAYS use `mysql_real_escape_string` when inserting values in the db.

**Then :**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Image` (`ImageId`, `ImageFile`) 
          VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"])."','".
                     mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["fileImage"]["name"])."'
          );";
```

Comment: This adds the tomporary file name as the ImageId which isn't what OP wants?